# Determine if the solution to the differential equation is unique

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'= \sqrt{ \frac{y}{x-2}}$$

As per the title, I am meant to determine if a solution is unique around a given point. The given points are:

$$y(2) = 0, y(2) = 1, y(3) = 0, y(3) = 1$$

My attempt at this was to first determine the region in which it is continuous. Pretty self explanatory.

$$x \neq 2$$

So, this immediately knocks out the first two points given, $y(2) = 0$ and $y(2) = 1$.

Now. The method that I know to determine uniqueness for a given point is that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, where $f(x, y)$ is the right portion of the differential equation, is continuous. Doing this gives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\sqrt{\frac{y}{x+2}} = \frac{y^{-1/2}}{2(x+2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

This means that it is a discontinuous equation at $0$. Does this mean that both $y(3) = 0$ and $y(3) = 1$ would both be unique solutions?

Comment: I have got this solution $$y(x)=\frac{1}{4} \left(4 c_1 \sqrt{x-2}+c_1^2+4 x-8\right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reasoning was right. To prove a solution is unique, my proposed method of evaluating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ at the given point and making sure it is continuous suffices. The solution for the given points would thus be continuous at $y(3) = 1$,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x-2}} = \frac{1}{2(1)(1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Which is indeed, continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but I can at least tell you which solutions are not unique.

First, note there is a constant solution: $y=0$. This solution satisfies $y(2)=0$ and $y(3)=0$

Directly solving the equation, using separation of variables gives

$$ \sqrt{y} = \sqrt{x-2} + c $$

where the constant $c$ is determined by the initial condition

$y(2)=0$ gives another solution $y = x+2$

$y(3)=0$ gives another solution $y = (\sqrt{x-2}-1)^2$

In your attempts, note that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x-2}} $$

is discontinuous at $y=0$. This should tell you something about the initial value.